# Maximum number of times that a natural number can appear in a given matrix

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, matrices

Let $N>2$. Consider the $N\times N$ symmetric matrix
\begin{equation}
A=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
0&d_1&d_1+d_2&d_1+d_2+d_3&\cdots &\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} d_i\\
d_1&0&d_2&d_2+d_3&\cdots &\sum_{i=2}^{N-1} d_i\\
d_1+d_2&d_2&0&d_3&\cdots &\sum_{i=3}^{N-1} d_i\\
d_1+d_2+d_3&d_2+d_3&d_3&0&\cdots &\sum_{i=3}^{N-1} d_i\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots &\vdots\\
\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} d_i&\sum_{i=2}^{N-1} d_i&\sum_{i=3}^{N-1} d_i&\sum_{i=4}^{N-1} d_i&\cdots &0\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
where each $d_i>0$ is a natural number. We see that the matrix is determined by the values $d_1,\dotsc,d_{N-1}$.

If $0<d=d_1=\cdots=d_{N-1}$, then $A$ is a Toeplitz matrix:
\begin{equation}
A=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
0&d&2d&3d&\cdots & (N-1)d\\
d&0&d&2d&\cdots &(N-2)d\\
2d&d&0&d&\cdots &(N-3)d\\
3d&2d&d&0&\cdots &(N-4)d\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots &\vdots\\
(N-1)d&(N-2)d&(N-3)d&(N-4)d&\cdots &0\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
Hence the number zero repeated $N$ times in $A$. Also, $d$ repeated $2(N-1)$ times; $2d$ repeated $2(N-2)$ times, $3d$ repeated $2(N-3)$ times, and so on.

**My question is**: for arbitrary $d_1,\dotsc, d_{N-1}$ positive natural numbers, is it possible to have some positive $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k$ appears more than $2(N-1)$ times in $A$? My intuition says that NO.

In other words, I want to show that a natural number $k>0$ can appear in $A$ at most $2(N-1)$ times.It's been awhile since I'm trying to prove it but didn't succeeded. 
Can someone help me to solve it?

**My attempt**

Suppose $k=\sum_{i=j}^{j+k}d_i$ for some $j\in\{1,\dotsc, N-1\}$ and some $k\in\{0,\dotsc,N-1-j\}$ and denote $A_k=\{d_j,\dotsc,d_{j+k}\}$. Define $$\bar A_k=\{\sum_{s\in A}s:A_k\subseteq A \text{ and } A\in\mathcal{P}(\{d_1,\dotsc,d_{N-1}\})\}$$
and 
$$\underline{A}_k=\{\sum_{s\in A}s:A\in\mathcal{P}(A_k)\}$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set. Then $k\notin (\bar A_k \cup\underline{A}_k)\setminus\{k\}$. Visually
[image]

I tried to use this inductively.

If $k$ is in the last diagonal, that is, $k=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}d_i$, then $\underline{A}_k=A$, and then $k$ can appear at most 2 times in $A$.

If $k$ is in the second last diagonal, then $k$ can appear at most 4 times in $A$.

In this fashion, I can visually see that the maximum number that $k$ can appear in $A$ is if $k$ is equal to all $d_1,\dotsc,d_{N-1}$. However, I cannot be precise in the proof.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to consider the half of the matrix above the diagonal. But there are only $N-1$ partial rows above the diagonal, and none of these partial rows can contain the same entry more than once since the $d_j$ are positive; so any given integer appears at most $N-1$ times above the diagonal.

(The same proof works if the $d_j$ are any positive real numbers. If we use the monotonicity of the columns as well, starting from the entry in row $N-1$ and column $N$, we can in fact prove that the only way $2(N-1)$ is achieved is in the example you gave.)

Comment: Oh! you are right! "None of the partial rows can contain k more than once". Thank you!